# Is there a way when I update the site, the cache is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, caching, service-worker, workbox

I am using React, and the service worker is activated and caches the static and everything is fine until now

The problem is when I make changes to the site and deploy the files
The site still displays the old version, which is the one that was cached before.
And I have to clear the data for the site to see the new version , which is the client will not do :(

Is there a way when I update the site, the cache is refreshed ?

btw I am using the initial service worker that comes with react(which uses "workbox") , and I didn't change any thing in it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find an answer [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#skip_the_waiting_phase). Read the caution disclamer carefully.

Comment: yes I did , thank you so much